# Как получить id нажатой кнопки?

Tags: button, javascript, html, ajax

Имеется функция getdetails() обработки нажатия (и отправка через Ajax), но теперь надо чтобы их было четыре, и js знал (получил цифру в переменную) какую именно нажали...

```
    input type="button" name="submit" id="1" value="A:..." onClick = "getdetails()" 
 ...    
input type="button" name="submit" id="4" value="D:..." onClick = "getdetails()"
```

Загугленный способ не знаю как совместить :
 `element.onclick = function(){ alert(this.id); }` 
или не делать их кнопками?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, так:

```
<input type="button" name="submit" id="1" value="A:..." onClick = "getdetails(this)">
<input type="button" name="submit" id="2" value="A:..." onClick = "getdetails(this)">

<script>
    function getdetails(obj) {
        alert(obj.id);
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: спасибо работает, оно как всегда просто)

Comment: Пожалуйста, но советую вам избегать подобных конструкций:

    onClick = "getdetails(this)"

а использовать addEventListener и attachEvent (IE8)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input class="type" type="button" name="submit" id="1">
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".type").on("click", function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(id);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: думал так, но кода больше)