# Как добавить стиль при нажатии на элемент?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

У меня есть такое меню:

```css
.dropdown-checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}

.dropdown-checkbox .label-title {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.dropdown-checkbox ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -120%;
  left: 114%;
  background: #cacaca;
  list-style: none;
  min-width: 180px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
}

.dropdown-checkbox ul li {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
  margin: 0px;
}

.dropdown-checkbox ul li input {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.dropdown-checkbox:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-checkbox">
  <label class="label-title"><p>SELECT</p></label>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Tom" v-model="selector">
      <label>Tom</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Bob" v-model="selector">
      <label>Bob</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Sam" v-model="selector">
      <label>Sam</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Alice" v-model="selector">
      <label>Alice</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы меню открывалось не при наведении(hover) на элемент, а при нажатии(click) на него.
Как добавить стиль display: block; при нажатии на элемент? Можно использовать vue/html/css/js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue-way:

HTML:

```
<label class="label-title" @click="visibility=!visibility"><p>SELECT</p></label>
<ul :class="{'visible': visibility}">...</ul>
```

JS (если уже есть data, просто добавляете туда `visibility`):

```
data: {
   visibility: false
}
```

CSS (`.dropdown-checkbox:hover ul` - это, естественно, сносим):

```
ul.visible {
    display: block !important;
}
```

И не надо городить всякие querySelector'ы, Vue создан, чтобы максимально обходиться без этого.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const p = document.querySelector('label');
const dropdown = document.querySelector('ul');

p.addEventListener('click', menuBlock)

function menuBlock(e){
  dropdown.classList.toggle('d');
}
```

```css
.dropdown-checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}

.dropdown-checkbox .label-title {
  font-size: 13px;

}

.dropdown-checkbox ul {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  bottom: -120%;
  left: 114%;
  background: #cacaca;
  list-style: none;
  min-width: 180px;
  /*margin: 0px;*/
  padding: 0px;
  /*display: none;*/
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
}

.dropdown-checkbox ul li {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
  margin: 0px;
}

.dropdown-checkbox ul li input {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

ul{
  display: none;
}

.d{
  display: block;
}

.label-title{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<label class="label-title"><p>SELECT</p></label>

<div class="dropdown-checkbox">

  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Tom" v-model="selector">
      <label>Tom</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Bob" v-model="selector">
      <label>Bob</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Sam" v-model="selector">
      <label>Sam</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" value="Alice" v-model="selector">
      <label>Alice</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

самое простое, что пришло на ум

```
function foo(){
  document.getElementById(<<id>>).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Делаете функцию с любыми доп условиями и вешаете её на кнопку

```
<button onclick="foo()" id=<<id>> </button>
```

id нажатой кнопки так же можно получить сразу, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/334196/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-id-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8) описано как.